# QGIS polyline to polygon error

Tags: qgis

I have a set of polylines in qgis saved as .shp but when the geometry lines to polygons tool is used it fills in the areas on the outside of the lines, forming some strange polygon. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

A screenshot of your result might help here. That being said, you could try the [**Topology Checker**](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_topology_checker.html) plugin and check for dangles. If you find a bunch, your lines may not be closing properly, so the tool can't form polygons as intended.

Also, there is a [GIS-themed Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/), which may answer your future questions better.